# Android :What is the difference between app signing certificate and upload certificate?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-games

What is the difference between app signing certificate and upload certificate?
I am having trouble with integrating Google Play Games with my app (I posted about this as another question) and I noticed that the one that is used for client Id that is automatically generated on Google API Console is called signing certificate.
However, what I can see when I run signing in report on Android Studio is called upload certificate.

Which one is supposed to set for client Id? By the way both didn't solve my problem but I am curious about the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Signing certificate**

> Certain Google Play services (such as Google Sign-in and App Invites)
>   require you to provide the SHA-1 of your signing certificate so we can
>   create an OAuth2 client and API key for your app.
>   For more info refer:[doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

**Upload certificate**

> When you publishing an app that is not signed by an upload key, the
>   Google Play Console provides the option to register one for future
>   updates to the app. Although this is an optional step, it’s
>   recommended that you publish your app with a key that’s separate from
>   the one Google Play uses to distribute your app to users. That way,
>   Google keeps your signing key secure, and you have the option to reset
>   a lost or compromised private upload key. This section describes how
>   to create an upload key, generate an upload certificate from it, and
>   register that certificate with Google Play for future updates of your
>   app.
>   For more info refer:[doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: I thought I can find my signing certificate easily by running signing report on Android Studio. But I cannot find the one. I can find upload certificate instead. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes,definitely.

Comment: Thanks appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Apps in the **Play Store** require to be signed in order to be released and/or updated on users' devices. That way no one, except you holding the key, can issue updates to your app. However, if you lose this key (named release key) everything is lost since you won't be able to update your app anymore.

So Google created **App Signing** where they hold that release key for you (to avoid the said situation) and instead you use an update key to issue new updates. Similarly as before, only you have access to this key, but if you lose it or it gets compromised you can always ask for a new one and/or revoke it, keeping your app unaffected since the release key is still safe in Google's servers.

That's why some services (such as yours) require you to give them the release certificate (not the key), which you can find in the App Integrity of the Play Store dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Another notice that if you're using both keys (actually you can choose to manage your key and not opt-in to Play App Signing, but I'm not mentioning this here):

- `upload key` (your local keystore): usually to submit the new app to PlayStore, but just to verify you submit the new version app, and to sign your APK to test locally, e.g. when distribute & install through APK to your teams/QC to test it.
- `signing key` (Google manage): when users download your app from Google Play, Internal Testing..., this app will re-sign with the signing key again

And then some services require sha fingerprint, e.g universal link, google sign in..., then **remember that submit sha fingerprint for both keys** (upload key & signing key) so these services can work normally for both local APK & PlayStore app

[image]